# Is it possible to access "internal" object properites defined in ES5-8.6.2?

Tags: javascript

By "internal" I mean those defined in **ES5 8.6.2**:

http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm

One can access the **[[Class]]** internal property by using

```
Object.prototype.toString(Object)
```

What are these properties for and are the accessible?

The specification does not claim to define a way to modify(p32-footer).

> NOTE This specification defines no ECMAScript language operators or
>   built-in functions that permit a program to modify an object‘s
>   [[Class]] or [[Prototype]] internal properties or to change the value
>   of [[Extensible]] from false to true. Implementation specific
>   extensions that modify [[Class]], [[Prototype]] or [[Extensible]] must
>   not violate the invariants defined in the preceding paragraph.

Comment: Doesn't "internal" mean exactly that they aren't supposed to be exposed? (As language features, I mean). Actually, they don't even have to be implemented, as long as the interpreter behaves as if they were.

Comment: What do you mean by "exposed"....the value of [[class]] is retrievable by the method above.

Comment: I edited my comment to clarify. I mean exposed *as language features*. Actually, others are exposed the way [[Class]] is, e.g. [[Value]]. And others can even be modified, like [[Enumerable]] in the case of property descriptors.

Comment: I was going to post that quote as an answer. They're just needed as artifacts to describe how the language behave. One more example (this time from the list in 8.6.2): [[GetOwnProperty]] seems to be exposed as `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor`.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyDescriptor

Comment: The reflect spec in es6 provides a lot of different methods to access internal functions

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Are they accessible?

Not quite, you can figure out what they return (based on their individual definitions [§8.12](http://es5.github.com/#x8.12)) but you can't change how they work.

Here are ways to work out most of them (listed in [§8.6.2](http://es5.github.com/#x8.6.2)).
For all examples, I'm assuming the object is stored as `obj` and property key is `name`, `val` is a value and `descriptor` is a property descriptor.

- `[[Prototype]]`, [`Object.getPrototypeOf(obj)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf)
- `[[Class]]`, [`Object.prototype.toString.call(obj)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString)
- `[[Extensible]]`, [`Object.isExtensible(obj)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/isExtensible)
- `[[Get]]`, `obj[name]`
- `[[GetOwnProperty]]`, [`Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj, name)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyDescriptor)
- `[[GetProperty]]`, `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj, name)` combined with going up inheritance (`Object.getPrototypeOf`)
- `[[Put]]`, `obj[name] = val`
- `[[CanPut]]`, Look up `getOwnPropertyDescriptor`, if *undefined* is `obj` extensible ([`Object.isExtensible`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/isExtensible))? Otherwise, check *writable* or existance of a setter *set*
- `[[HasProperty]]`, [`name in obj`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in)
- `[[Delete]]`, [`delete obj.name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete)
- `[[DefaultValue]]`, not sure about this one
- `[[DefineOwnProperty]]`, [`Object.defineProperty(obj, name, descriptor)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)

> What are these properties for?

They're to do with the internal mechanics of how the JavaScript engine should work according to the specification ([§8.12](http://es5.github.com/#x8.12)), and are referred to in algorithms ([example](http://es5.github.com/#x15.4.4.4)).

---

## ES6+

In ES6 we have access to [`Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy)s, this means we can create objects and then wrap them with a `Proxy` to let us handle get, set, has, etc in a custom way

```
// have some object
let o = {};
// wrap with proxy defining a get handler and set handler
let p = new Proxy(o, {
    get(t, n) {
        console.log(t, n, t[n]);
        return t[n];
    },
    set(t, n, v) {
        t[n] = +v;
        return true;
    }
});

// now accessing via proxy
p.foo; // undefined
// get handler logs Object o, "foo", undefined (this happens before .foo returns)

p.foo = '123'; // uses handler to sets on `o`
p.foo; // 123, notice value is Number due to set handler
// get handler logs Object o, "foo", 123 (this happens before .foo returns)
```

Comment: Can you give an example of how to use the [[Put]] & [[Delete]] properties?

Comment: @Cody I'm not entirely sure what you're asking beyond what I have already in the answer. Maybe you want a combined example.. say you have some  `stateObj = {}`, can toggle existence of a property _foo_ `if (stateObj.hasOwnProperty('foo')) /* [[Delete]] */ delete stateObj.foo; else /* [[Put]] */ stateObj.foo = true;`

Comment: @Paul_S, thanks for the reply. What I meant was, instead of interpolating a `[[Set]]` like `Object.defineProperty({}, 'key', { set: function(){...} });` -- how to interpolate `[[Put]]`s (?). More like, `Object.defineProperty({}, '[[Put]]', function(){ alert('new property added!'); });` so that its possible to track when new properties are added to an object.

Comment: @Cody I think you've misunderstood the exposure of these. You can't do that, it would be like asking to change a type of tea after you've made your drink. If you want to modify such things, you would have to make the changes to the engine and compile it yourself.

Comment: Objects have internal methods to modify how [[Get]]s and [[Sets]]s work. CRUD operations (Create, Read, Update, and Delete -- map to Put, Get, Set, Delete) such as [[Get]] and [[Set]] are modifiable -- its not far-fetched to think [[Put]] and [[Delete]] would be too. The only difference is that they're on a different scale (Object as opposed to Object-property scale). In other words, I JUST changed my "type" of tea when I modded Get & Set -- and be careful when using "type" in that sentence: I'm not changing its type -- its still an Object; I'm just changing an internal method, [[Put]].

Answer (score -1):

### Yes,

They *are* accessible:

```
Object.defineProperty({}, 'key', {
    get: function(){
        console.log('GOT %s', 'key');
        return someValue;
    },
    set: function(value){
        console.log('SET %s', 'key');
        this[key] = value;
    }
});
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
var object = {
    _name: '',
    get name(){ return this._name; },
    set name(value){ this._name = value; }
};
```

However, I don't yet know how to access [[Put]] & [[Delete]] -- please elaborate if you do.

Comment: Hi again @Cody, I havea present for you; I came across this the other day and (assuming you still need it and are in an environment that can use it) thought it might be related to what you want to do https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy

Comment: @Paul S. This is awesome news! I came across Proxies in a very very small tutorial and wasn't sure if it was what I was looking for. Thanks a ton for this! You should write a small Gist and publish it under this comment ;) ... That is, if you're already pretty familiar with Proxy (I'm not).